# Is my design a split plot and what analysis will be appropriate?

Tags: mixed-model, anova

This is the first time I'm asking a question here.
I'm working on a field experiment that has been running for three years. The experiment was established before I started my studies, so I was not part of designing it. The initial plan was a split plot design but due to constraints they could not do that efficiently. The response (yield) is measured multiple times in a season, so I understand this could be analyzed as repeated measures.

I've made a simplified picture below.
The yellow blocks represent full irrigation and the blue blocks, deficit irrigation. The smaller plot with numbers are species of plants (treatments). The treatments replicate twice in each block. We harvest plant four times a season. My question is, can I analyze my data as split plot design? Will it be better to include harvest as factor or as repeated measure? Or should I analyze each harvest separately?
Thanks for your answers.

[image]